# gem mirror segfaulting

Tags: ruby, mirror, rubygems, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create rubygems mirror on my VDS doing the following:

```
$ gem mirror
$ gem generate_index -d /home/rubygems/mirror
```

The problem that each time I run first command ruby segfaults with following message:

```
fetching: http://rubygems.org/Marshal.4.8.Z
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/version.rb:156: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted
```

System OS: Ubuntu 9.10 Server. I have a theory that my VDS could be low on RAM (1GB total, about 550MB free). Can anyone shed some light on this?